# pthread_cond_timedwait_monotonic_np issue waiting for ~30ms even timeout value is 0

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using ndk-8 to compile the following code. When I run the application timedwait is consuming ~30ms wait even if timeout value passed is 0.

```
int TimedWait(uint32_t timeoutInMs)
{        
    struct timespec monotonicTime;
    int retval = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &monotonicTime);
    monotonicTime.tv_sec += timeoutInMs / 1000;
    monotonicTime.tv_nsec += (timeoutInMs % 1000) * 1000000L;

    if (monotonicTime.tv_nsec >= 1000000000L)
    {
        monotonicTime.tv_sec += monotonicTime.tv_nsec / 1000000000L;
        monotonicTime.tv_nsec = monotonicTime.tv_nsec % 1000000000L;
    }

    pthread_cond_timedwait_monotonic_np(&v_Cond, &v_Mutex, &monotonicTime);
}
```

Comment: Did you try `pthread_cond_timedwait()` instead?

Comment: Thanks Serhio, pthread_cond_timedwait() worked, provided I have to use CLOCK_REALTIME instead of CLOCK_MONOTONIC